# Search for existence of sensitive substring without revealing substring in cleartext

Tags: cryptography, privacy, algorithm

I have a list of very sensitive strings and I want to ensure that these strings do not exist in a set of documents (potentially very large documents).

However, these substrings are *so* sensitive that I don't want the third-party performing the search to ever see or have any access to my substrings in clear text.

The 3rd party in this context is a system that I operate but I do not have authority to have this sensitive data exist on this system in cleartext nor do I have authority to have the data on that system exist elsewhere (like pulling down to a laptop and searching for cleartext).

I just want a simple yes/no answer from the algorithm as to whether my substrings are found.

A very naive poorly performing solution is to provide the substrings as hashes and the third-party can hash all substrings of the documents to arrive at an answer.

Is there a better way, is there an algorithm designed for this purpose?

Comment: The famous work of Song [Practical Techniques for Searches on Encrypted Data](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dawnsong/papers/se.pdf). Also. slow but homomorphic search can be made. Can the search results reveal a pattern [How can frequency analysis be applied to modern ciphers?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/74786/18298)?

Comment: What about performing the search where the sensitive strings reside, the "system" just sends the text and then receives back the results of the search.

Answer (score 1):

If your sensitive information is formatted in a particular way (e.g. credit cards being 13-19 digits) you can search for candidates which MAY be your sensitive string, then apply your hashing idea to the candidates.

If you're searching for a specific phrase, like "UFO's are real", you could use regex to search for any string matching "[A-Z]{3}'\w\s\w{3}\s\w{4}", provided it's acceptable to leak information about the length and structure of the phrase. You can then compare the hash of each result with the hash of the original to see if it's present.

Answer (score 0):

> A very naive poorly performing solution is to provide the substrings as hashes and the third-party can hash all substrings of the documents to arrive at an answer.

Apart from poor performance (which, as [Maybe_Factor's answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/224753/61744) points out, may partially be offset if your "secret strings" have some recognizable structure that can be used to limit the number of candidate document-strings that need to be hashed), there is a ***potential security vulnerability*** to this approach... if the third-party finds that a hash of part of one of the plain-text documents matches one of the hashes of your "super-secret strings", then ***they now know that super-secret string***, since they have a bit of plain-text that hashes to it!

---

If your strings are sufficiently secret that the above is a problem, I strongly *suspect* that there is little chance of finding a way around this, especially if the secret strings could occur at (almost) any position in the target documents.

I believe encrypting both the secret strings and the documents (before passing them to the third-party) is not likely to work, since all the encryption methods I know (that are worth using) take pains to ensure that the encrypted versions of the three documents:

```
...SECRET-STRING.......
.....SECRET-STRING.....
.......SECRET-STRING...
```

won't contain a common string corresponding to the encryption of `SECRET-STRING`. (A simple Caesar cipher *would* allow such searching, but would be trivially easy for the third-party to reverse if the documents-to-be-checked contain any moderately recognizable text).

Applying a "standard" encryption algorithm to every document, at every offset (or, possibly, every offset up to the "block size") might get around this problem, but by the time *you'd* done this, you may as well just performed the search yourself.